# Master View in Iphone

Tags: ios4

I had asp.net back ground and now developing apps for Iphone. I have been wondering is there some thing master view or theme for app as we had master pages for website designing in asp dotnet  which make the whole website design generic 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you really don't have anything similar. You do get two great application templates, the Tab based view or the Navigation based. In the navigation controller certain things follow each view like the style of the navigation bar but that is it.

If you want to use something like PhoneGap and drop that into XCode then use a web based UI framework like jqTouch, then you can have a template :) but that is a completely different application model.

Answer (score 0):

Master View? I'm not sure what you mean by this. You have a Window (UIWindow) that you add Views to (UIView). You only have one window, but are free to have as many Views as you like.

So it depends what you want to add, for example i have a banner that i want at the tope of evert screen. I added the ImageView to the window and scaled the Views so they left the top of the window showing.

If you wanted to add some default behaviour to your Views and or add an image view to every view. You could simply subclass UIViewController and go from there?

If you give a touch more detail about what you want to achieve I'll gladly go into more detail.

Comment: actually i am working on enterprise app which has same functionality but different user has different theme so i had to rework on each user   thats why I am thinking about some thing like master page or view that i changes then the UI of whole app will change

Comment: I'd probably create a theme manager dependant on the user simply select and apply the correct theme.